# Preprocessor for assets in AEM as a cloud service

Tags: aem, aem-6

Environment - AEM as Cloud Service

Do you know of any OSGI service or interface which i can use to hook up a service to run a few validations on an asset before the asset compute services kick-in to process the asset ?
To be more specific, I'm looking at building a few validation rules like

- asset should follow a particular naming convention
- assets can only be uploaded to their designated paths, etc

I want to restrict the asset from being processed if it does not pass any of the validation rules. Where can i write this logic ?

I'm aware of [post-processing logic](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-cloud-service/content/assets/manage/asset-microservices-configure-and-use.html?lang=en#post-processing-workflows) but I'm looking for a pre-processing one ? Any leads or ideas to implement this will be highly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: @ronnyfm there is no such thing as a preprocessing hook mate, got to overlay fileupload.js to drive this logic unfortunately :(